# How to make integer element value in xsd not become zero when no value entered in SOAP XML?

Tags: java, soap, xsd, jaxb, spring-ws

I have a java web service application built with jaxb and spring webservice.

I have a complex type in a xsd like this:

```
...

<complexType name="GetRecordsRequest">
    <sequence>
        <element name="maxRecords" type="int" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

...
```

Using **xjc**, I had the jaxb class generated from xsd:

```
public class GetRecordsRequest {
    protected int maxRecords;

    public int getMaxRecords() {
        return maxRecords;
    }

    public void setMaxRecords(int value) {
        this.maxRecords = value;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is if I entered empty value for maxRecords in soap request xml from **SoapUI** application like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/ns1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:GetRecordsRequest>
         <ns1:maxRecords></ns1:maxRecords>
      </ns1:GetRecordsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got the value of **maxRecords** is 0 in webservice endpoint class method. I expected the application will throw error or Exception because I had set **minOccurs="1"** in xsd, I thought it means mandatory.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace="http://www.test.com/ns1", localPart = "GetRecordsRequest")
public JAXBElement<GetRecordsResponse> GetRecordsRequest(JAXBElement<GetRecordsRequest> jaxbGetListMessage){
    GetRecordsRequest request = jaxbGetListMessage.getValue();

    System.out.println(request.getMaxRecords());    // print 0 value

    ...
}
```

**I even changed the minOccurs to 0 in xsd so the type become Integer, but the maxRecords value is still 0, I expected it would be null.**

The only way around I know is to change the type of maxRecords to string or token, but I preferred if there is another solution with still maintaining its integer type.

**So, how to make the maxRecords value is null or exception occured when I entered empty value in the soap xml?**

**Note:** I have simplified the code/xml above by removing unrelated parts to make the code easier to read. If you found a syntax typo, please let me know in the comment sections since I typed the most of codes manually.

Comment: Did you implement a PayloadValidatingInterceptor ?

Comment: Since you don't validate the request, it doesn't matter what you try in the XSD. Make sure you use a `PayloadValidatingInterceptor` like @Amine mentions to validate the requests with the XSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow suggestion from the others to use **PayloadValidatingInterceptor** and I add something like this in the app. context xml and it works:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validatingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/webservice.xsd" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Thanks to everyone that suggest using PayloadValidatingInterceptor.

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive in Java so it cannot be null. You could use the Integer-type instead. An Integer is nullable so it won't default to 0.

Comment: My XSD looks like this and it generates an Integer, not an int. <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>

Comment: yes, it generates an Integer, but  `System.out.println(request.getMaxRecords());` still print the value 0. I even had confirmed it by setting breakpoint in the code in the eclipse. The `getMaxRecords()` definitely has Integer return type but I still got 0 value. Only if I removed the `<ns1:maxRecords></ns1:maxRecords>` from the soap xml, I got null value.